# Parse json in Athena directly from S3

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, parsing, amazon-athena

```
{"date":"2023-03-13T20:34:02.764Z","service":"Test",
"attributes":{"RequestPath":"/test/LogInfo",
"Message":"Request { source: \"SNSMessage Log Request: \", requestBody: \"{\\\"RecLoc\\\":\\\"MM123Q\\\",\\\"FlightInfo\\\":{\\\"Origin\\\":\\\"IAH\\\",\\\"Destination\\\":\\\"EWR\\\",\\\"FlightNumber\\\":\\\"1657\\\",\\\"CarrierCode\\\":\\\"SS\\\",\\\"SegmentId\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"FlightDate\\\":\\\"04/11/2023 11:15:00\\\"},\\\"CustomerInfo\\\":{\\\"MileagePlusNumber\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"MemberStatus\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"FirstName\\\":null,\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"Tester\\\"},\\\"CustomerAction\\\":{\\\"EventSource\\\":4,\\\"Status\\\":null,\\\"ErrorCode\\\":0,\\\"EventCode\\\":4002,\\\"EventDescription\\\":\\\"This is the test\\\"},\\\"ServiceInfo\\\":{\\\"SessionId\\\":\\\"xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx\\\",\\\"ClientId\\\":\\\"xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx\\\"},\\\"UniqueEventId\\\":\\\"xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx49c\\\",\\\"Messages\\\":[{\\\"Key\\\":\\\"testing\\\",\\\"Value\\\":\\\"{Test Successful..}{test Successful..}{Testing Successful..}\\\"}],\\\"Transit\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"Transaction_Id\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"ApplicationId\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"MachineName\\\":\\\"\\\"}\", transactionId: null }","RequestId":"123222","LogTime":"03/13/2023 20:34:02.716609+00:00","source":"stdout","LogLevel":"Information","ActionName":"Test.Test.Service.Controllers.Test.LogInfo (Test.TrcLogs.Service)","ServiceName":"Test (6.0.5.0)","service":"cea-Test-qa","TraceLogInfo":{"GlobalTransactionId":"xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"},"Environment":"QA","ClientId":"Teting_TTT_xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx","SessionId":"xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx","timestamp":1678739642764},"_id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","source":"csharp","status":"info","tags":["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","region:XXXXXXXXXX","container_id:f6f28946c63d4bf88e2878148763aec7-873039855","task_version:55","task_family:XXXXXXXXXXXX_qa","applicationci:cea","env:qa","task_arn:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","source:csharp","container_name:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"]}
```

Hello, I need to parse each field as from json in an Amazon athena query. I can access
`select attributes.message` but when I am trying to access `CarrierCode`, I can't access it. How can I access `REcLoc` and `Flight Number` inside `FlightInfo`?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, the SNS Message inside that file is not stored in JSON format due to all of the backslashes. Are you able to control how those files are created? You might be able to use [Amazon SNS raw message delivery - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html) to obtain the message in its 'raw' form, rather than encapsulated within another message.

Comment: What is the result of `select typeof(attributes.message)`?

Comment: select typeof(attributes.message) is varchar, as per comments i think i have to enable raw SNS delivery or manually remove all slashes with in query

Comment: what do you think about as this statement return json typeof(cast(attributes.message as json))

Comment: @SaqibShaikh can you please add a single result of `select attributes.message ...`?

Comment: @GuruStron its return empty rows

Comment: i have resolved this by replacing all slashes with ''